# SQL query to retrieve data from 3 tables in a database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: `admin`, `student`, `tutor`.

In each table there are many columns.
Among them there are 2 columns with same name and datatype which are `username` and `password` in all the three tables.

I have to retrieve those 2 columns from the 3 tables in a single query, is it possible?

Comment: Google "Aliases in MySQL"; you will find good tutorials on it. Also, Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: I'm not sure an alias is the right hint here. Instead `UNION` or `JOIN` depending on how this output is supposed to look (not specified here though). My money is on UNION.

Comment: Is there any relationship among the tables?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it, you can use query like this one:

```
SELECT username, password FROM admin
UNION
SELECT username, password FROM student
UNION
SELECT username, password FROM tutor;
```